# Flutter using OpenContainer and pass data to another screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using the `animation` library and `OpenContainer` class in Flutter. This class has two methods, one of which displays a widget, and in the other, a different widget can be displayed with animation after being clicked.
dart

```dart
OpenContainer<String>(
  closedShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
  openShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
  openBuilder: (_, closeContainer) => SearchPage(closeContainer),
  onClosed: (res) {
    print('test');
  },
  tappable: false,
  closedBuilder: (_, openContainer) => SubCategoriesContainerBar(
    categories: categories!,
    openContainer: openContainer,
  ),
)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to send selected data to `SearchPage` when `SubCategoriesContainerBar` is closed.

One way to do this is to use the `onClosed` function in `OpenContainer`. In `onClosed`, you can implement your logic for navigating to the `SearchPage`. To do this, you can use the Navigator class and the push function to navigate to the `SearchPage`.

i think i can use `Provider` library but i'm not sure how can i use it

Comment: From the docs: "T refers to the type of data returned by the route when the container is closed. This value can be accessed in the onClosed function.". You correctly say that you can implement the logic there, so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: From what I understood, you’re trying to pass data from the SubCategoriesContainerBar widget to the SearchPage widget when the SubCategoriesContainerBar is closed, You can use a callback function that is passed from the `SearchPage` widget to the `SubCategoriesContainerBar`  widget with using `onDataSelected` function where you can access selected data. 
If this is not what you want and you need instructions on using a `Provider`, let me know.